# Yii: default scope applied twice to join query

Tags: php, sql, orm, yii

I have two models:

```
class Tag extends CActiveRecord {
    //// ......

    public function defaultScope(){ 
        return array(
            'condition' => 'class_name = :class_name',
            'params' => array(':class_name' => get_class($this))
       );
    }

    public function relations(){
        return array(
            'videos' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Video', 'tags_videos(tag_id, video_id)')
        );
    }

    //// ......
}

class Video extends CActiveRecord {
    //// .......

    public function relations(){
        return array(
            'tags' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', 'tags_videos(video_id, tag_id)')
        );
    }

    //// .......
}
```

When I do `$video_instance->tags` I'm getting this error:

```
 exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `tags`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `tags`.`name` AS `t1_c1`, `tags`.`orig_name` AS `t1_c2`, `tags`.`slug` AS `t1_c3`, `tags`.`flags` AS `t1_c4`, `tags`.`class_name` AS `t1_c5`, `tags`.`created_at` AS `t1_c6` FROM `tags` `tags`  INNER JOIN `tags_videos` `tags_tags` ON (`tags_tags`.`video_id`=:ypl0) AND (`tags`.`id`=`tags_tags`.`tag_id`) AND (class_name = :class_name) WHERE (class_name = :class_name)' in /srv/http/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:528
```

My question is: why my default scope is applied twice to query (in WHERE and in ON) and how do I fix this?

Yii version: 1.1.12.b600af
PHP: 5.4.8

Comment: whats the code your using to call the relation? a simple $video->tags ?

Comment: yes, just $video_instance->tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define `'scopes'=>array( 'resetScope' )` in relation

```
public function relations(){
        return array(
            'tags' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', 'tags_videos(video_id, tag_id)','scopes'=>array( 'resetScope' ))
        );
}
```

There was a bug around it lately, and I am not sure if it's fixed in your version:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1197

Some more reference to look at:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12025-relation-without-default-scope/

Comment: it seems thats not fixed at all. it is issue of Yii, also when not using params it works

Comment: Where should I declare `resetScope`? in Tag or in Video?